# Changing observable property of observable causes subscription on parent object to be triggered

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, subscription, observable

I have an observable, say myValue. This observable has some properties, like id, also observable. I defined a custom binding to take care of myValue alterations.
When I change the value of the observable property id, the custom binding for myValue is triggered.
This is higly undesirable, because update function in my custom binding is very expensive and I experience performance issues. 
Is there a way to prevent parent observables to be updated along with its unpdated child?

The core parts of code

```
 //model opening, declaration, initialize...
 //In the model
 var self = this;
 this.myValue = ko.observable();
 this.myValue("Some value");
 this.myValue.id = 123;

 this.changeId = function() {
 self.myValue.id(111); //here the update for myValue is triggered
 }

 //After the model
 ko.bindingHandlers.customBinding = {
   init: function init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) 
     {/*nothing*/},
   update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
     /*expensive code*/
     console.log("I am being executed every time myValue.id() is changed...");
   }
 }

 //Then the model is applied...
 ko.applyBindings(model);
```

EDIT: I imply if there is a way to alter myValue.id without removing its observable nature. Declaring myValue.id not observable could solve the problem, but I'd need it to be observable, so I would use this solution only as last change.
Anyway, would declaring myValue.id not observable solve the problem? I didn't checked it yet

Comment: Yes, just do not use an observable. It will still get two-way binding, but it will not do any notifications. You will have to do those yourself. Related fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/841rsfk3/

Comment: Yes, I tried and saw non observable properties, when changed, do not trigger subscriptions or bindings on parent observable. There is not any way to prevent update to "bubble" to parent observable so?

Comment: Maybe. Right now I think your code wouldn't even run, though, so I can't say for sure. `this.myValue.id = 123;` and `self.myValue.id(111);` would blow up I think.

Comment: It is inside a function constructor, so when declared, the model is something like var model = new ModelConstructor(); This way this refers to the newly created model object "model", passed to ko.applyBindings. I am sorry not to have posted all code, I was just focusing on my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you could try something like this:

```
var myValue = ko.observable();
myValue.attributes = { id: ko.observable() };
```

Then a change to `myValue.attributes.id` should not bubble up to `myValue` since there is a non-observable object between the two, but I haven't tested it.

**EDIT**

Sorry to hear that this did not work. My last idea, and this is an ugly hack, would be to throttle the observable update.

```
var myValue = ko.observable();
myValue.id = ko.observable()
               .extend({ rateLimit: { timeout: Integer.MAX_VALUE, method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" } });
```

This waits for `Integer.MAX_VALUE`ms each time the id has changed before propagating the change and resets when there is a new change in that time. In a real world solution, this should effectively disable the event propagation, but it is, as I said, a hack. Maybe a custom extender could be written in much the same way as the rateLimit one which would do the desired thing, but I don't know the KO source.

Comment: It is very interesting, I am going to test it asaic

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Edited a typo in your answer (id = -> id: ). The valueHasMutated still propagates up to parent observable, jumping the "attributes" layer property. Good try, but unluckily does not work.

Comment: It is a little tricky in effect, I believe that all theese ratelimits things create a timer each one. Having multiple controls like this can easily overrun the browser with expensive multiple timers all around.

Comment: I fully agree. If it is critical I guess you'd really need to check out the source and see if you can customize it.